# IntelliJ remote debug works only once

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

We've recently moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ. When configuring remote debugging, it manage to connect to the process once (via host and port) and debugging works. However, after disconnecting, we cannot connect to the process again. IntelliJ shows:

```
Unable to open debugger port (itstl060:33411) java.net.ConnectException "Connection Refused"
```

This works in Eclipse and we can connect multiple times without any issues. Any idea if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your previous debugging service has stopped. Sometimes it may be still running. I have come across these kind of issues.

Comment: I think that this might be it. I've tried it again now and this is working (I was not able to reproduce it now) - thanks!